# Is Baumslag's one-relator group $\langle a,b: a = [a,a^b]\rangle$ countably dominated?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let us consider the short celebrated article [G. Baumslag, [A non-cyclic one-relator group all of whose finite quotients are cyclic](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700007783), Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society, Volume 10 , Issue 3–4 , November 1969 , pp. 497–498.]

The group in the title is defined as follows:
$$G = \langle a,b: a = [a,a^b]\rangle$$ where $a^b=b^{-1}ab$ and $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ as usual.

QUESTION: Does $G$ satisfy the following property?

There is a set $\{X_i: i\in \omega\}$ consisting of (some countably many) proper subgroups of $G$ such that  every proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in some $X_i$ for some $i\in \omega$ (such groups are called “countably dominated”).

Comment: Note that for a f.g. group, countably dominated means that the set of maximal (proper) subgroups is countable.

Comment: We consider CD-groups in [On groups that are dominated by countably many proper subgroups
Ahmet Arikan , Giovanni Cutolo , Derek J.S. Robinson, J of Algebra, 509 (2018), 445-466]. Some authors uses the term  “countable cofinality” instead of “countably dominated”.

Comment: Countable cofinality is used for something else, which seems quite unrelated, namely that $G$ is the union of a strictly increasing sequence of subgroups.

Comment: Some context would help. What happens for free groups? How about the (1,2)-Baumslag—Solitar group?

Comment: How about the number of maximal subgroups of G? If $G$ has  countably many maximal subgroups (such groups are called CG-groups), then we can use them as $X_i$ ($i\in \omega)$.